# vtiger ovh hosting recover deleted database

Tags: database, windows, vtiger, data-recovery

I have vtiger installed in an OVH hosted server (windows). I re-installed vtiger and wamp and loose my vtiger database. I have not any backup.

Is there any way to recover my database ?

Comment: Have you deleted old wamp directory?

Comment: Yes it is deleted.

Comment: Ohh.. Then as per my view no chance to recover,

Comment: After some researches, I found something interesting. With professional version of windows (windows 7 pro in my case), it is possible to restore a file or folder with previous versions (if you have one). I followed : [official windows help to recover lost or deleted files](http://windows.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows7/recover-lost-or-deleted-files).
After this, my previous vtiger database was back.